# Android Studio 2.2 update cause DefaultManifestParser cannot be resolve

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.2

Recently I updated android studio to android studio 2.2 and using gradle 2.14.1. However, com.android.builder.core.DefaultManifestParser cannot be resolve after the update. Below are the codes that I am using. Any recommend workaround to solve this issue? Thanks

```
defaultConfig {
    def manifestParser = new DefaultManifestParser(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile)
    applicationId = manifestParser.getPackage()
    versionName = manifestParser.getVersionName()
    versionCode manifestParser.getVersionCode()
    minSdkVersion manifestParser.getMinSdkVersion()
    targetSdkVersion manifestParser.getTargetSdkVersion()
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My defaultConfig setting is similar to yours and it's successfully built,

```
defaultConfig {
    def manifestFile = (File) android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile
    def manifestParser = new DefaultManifestParser(manifestFile)

    //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
    applicationId = manifestParser.getPackage()
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
    //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
    versionName = manifestParser.getVersionName()
    //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
    versionCode = manifestParser.getVersionCode()
}
```

so I guess probably the required ***.jar** hasn't been successfully downloaded during the IDE update. Could you double check whether the file **builder-2.2.0.jar** exists under the IDE folder(e.g., C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio_2.2\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\build\builder\2.2.0). If it does exist, can do a further checking to make sure the file **DefaultManifestParser.class** is really inside folder \com\android\builder\core by extracting **builder-2.2.0.jar**.

If the above mentioned file and class do exist, can also try using **import com.android.builder.core.DefaultManifestParser**, however, it's a bit weird that we have to use this.

Just think of there is another thing to check is the Gradle plugin class path, it should be like this
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'`

Answer (score -1):

I have same trouble，and reback gradle version to 2.1.3 it is working

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
}
```